# ColorPicker with only 3 colors in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm using a FXML document where I put all my Buttons and Menues. I want to open a `ColorPicker` by clicking in one of these buttons and this should propose me only 3 Colors (Green, Blue and Red) I don't want to see this :

[image: Normal ColorPicker]

I only want to see three color in this.

Comment: If you want to specifically limit the user to three colors, why not use a `ComboBox<Color>`?

Comment: Use a custom [`ComboBoxPopupControl`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/ComboBoxPopupControl.html) and implement `  getPopupContent​()` accordingly.

Comment: Or you can add HBox or VBox for example and include 3 panes with needed colors background. It's simple to customize this decision

Comment: thanks I will check for these solutions